# Is "than was wise" grammatically correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions

> That third night he found his way more quickly than before. He was walking so fast he knew he was making more noise **than was wise**, but he didn't meet anyone.
>
> —J.K. Rowling, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

Why isn't there any subject before 'than'? Usually 'subject + verb' or just nouns comes after 'more than~', as in "Harsh treatment by her mother-in-law was more than she could bear.", and "We prize liberty more than life."

But here, there's no subject and an adjective 'wise' came after 'was'. I don't understand the grammatical structure here, thus I'm also having difficulty understanding what this sentence means.

Comment: This is an _ellipsis_. In English, good writers often _elide_ a word or phrase which is understood by the reader to be present. Here, the repeated verb is is elided (or omitted) in the form of the infinitive _"to make"_ . The clause as understood is _"he was making more noise than was wise [to make]"_. The sentence means: "He was walking so fast that he knew he was making more noise than it was wise for him to make, but in spite of that, he didn't meet anyone."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second term in a comparative construction with *so A that B*, *as A as B*, *more A than B* always deletes at least one term (the term expressing the value compared) and often deletes considerably more. For instance:

> John makes **more money than Tim makes** <s>X much money</s> →
>   John makes **more money than Tim** <s>makes X much money</s>

The deletion readily includes the subject and the verb if those are recoverable from context:

> John gave Mildred **more money than** <s>he gave</s> **Tim** <s>X much money</s>

In your example the deletion extends to the subject:

> ... he was making **more noise than it was wise to make** <s>X much noise</s> →
>   ... he was making **more noise than** <s>it</s> **was wise** <s>to make X much noise</s>

Comment: Could this also be a deletion of _for him to make_ from  _more noise than [it] was wise [for him to make]_? I was about to try cramming that into my comment but ran into the old _hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Fersher. It's a sort of linguistic archaeology, reconstructing a whole dinosaur from one toenail that's left.